# Get previous and next 10 words after regex match

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get previous and next 10 words after the match

My Regex in PHP

```
(?:\S+\s*){0,5}\S*“your age”\S*(?:\s*\S+){0,10}
```

Paragraph I am matching

> if you have completed 28 years since the entered date of birth, the number 28 would be shown in that text box. Beside the text box titled “your age”, you would see another text box titled “You Born At”. This box would show you clear details of your birth date including the day on which you were born

What I want before and after 10 words of **“your age”**

> shown in that text box. Beside the text box titled “your age”, you would see another text box titled “You Born At”.

Comment: If this needs to be accurate, and for example also match compound words such as "won't", you should use a tokenizer instead of a regex pattern to detect words.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using `preg_replace`:

```
$input = "if you have completed 28 years since the entered date of birth, the number 28 would be shown in that text box. Beside the text box titled “your age”, you would see another text box titled “You Born At”. This box would show you clear details of your birth date including the day on which you were born";
$match = preg_replace("/^.*?((?:\S+\s+){10}“your age”(?:\S+\s+){10}).*$/", "$1", $input);
echo $match;
```

This prints:

```
shown in that text box. Beside the text box titled “your age”, you would see another text box titled “You Born
```

I used the following pattern to match the entire string, while capturing the `your age` term along with 10 words on either side of it:

```
^.*?((?:\S+\s+){10}“your age”(?:\S+\s+){10}).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

@TimBiegeleisen Thanks, i also found an other solution that actually i little faster.

```
(?:\S+\s){0,10}\S*“your age”\S*(?:\s\S+){0,10}
```

For my Code

```
$input = "if you have completed 28 years since the entered date of birth, the number 28 would be shown in that text box. Beside the text box titled “your age”, you would see another text box titled “You Born At”. This box would show you clear details of your birth date including the day on which you were born";
$match = preg_replace("/(?:\S+\s){0,10}\S*“your age”\S*(?:\s\S+){0,10}", $input, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

This will print

```
shown in that text box. Beside the text box titled “your age”, you would see another text box titled “You Born At”.
```